# Pandas repeating indexes drop rows on groupby where a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a specific operation I wasn't able to find the appropriate solution and hope you might have a way to help me figure it out.

Taking the following dataframe where we have multiple rows per id (as it is a recording per second of a value)

```
idx = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4])
value1 = np.array([600, 600, 600, 2.37, 4.57, 700, 700, 1.4, 2.5, 3.8, 500, 500, 2])
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': idx, 'value':value1}).set_index('id')

The dataframe looks like:

id | value
 1    600
 1    600
 1    600
 1    2.37
 1    4.57
 2    700
 2    700
 2    1.4
 2    2.5
 2    3.8
 4    500
 4    500
 4     2
```

I would like to drop certain rows to obtain this result dataframe

```
id | value
 1    2.37   
 1    4.57
 2    1.4
 2    2.5
 2    3.8
 4     2
```

where for each IDs, I only keep the rows where **value** is inferior to the **max value of this grouped by ID** (< df.groupby("id")[value].max()).

Meaning:

For id 1, df[value]< 600

For id 2, df[value]< 700

For id 3, df[value]< 500

Is there a more elegant/efficient solution than creating a new column to fill it in with the max and then compare each "value" to its max (as I'm working with high volume datasets (millions of records) ?

```
df[max_value_id] = df.groupby(['id'])['value'].transform(max)

df[df[value] < df[max_value_id]]
```

Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: I think your solution is already efficient, if you want to skip the auxillary column just directly slice it from the mask, like so: `df[df['value'] < df.groupby(['id'])['value'].transform(max)]`

Comment: Ok thanks then! I don't know why I was sure I could improve the way to do it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using a **mask** based on results of `transform()` provides this result.

```
df.loc[df.value<df.groupby("id")["value"].transform("max")]
```

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.37 |
| 1 | 4.57 |
| 2 | 1.4 |
| 2 | 2.5 |
| 2 | 3.8 |
| 4 | 2 |

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll stick to the transform method then, was not sure it was the most efficient one :) Thanks again